# Cucumber splits JSON string wrong in Java

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

When I using Cucumber in Java test, it seems something wrong with the JSON string as input, e.g.

```
Scenario Outline: not work
Given anythin
When I use <body> as body to call <url>
Then I'll get a status code of <status>

Examples:
| body    | url             | status        | 
| {"id":5}| /rest/update/0  | 404           |
```

And the error shows:

```
You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

@When("^I use {\"([^\"]*)\":(\\d+)} as body to call \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void i_use_as_body_to_call(String arg1, int arg2, String arg3) throws Throwable {
// Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
throw new PendingException();
```

}

But in fact, the whole JSON string should not be split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't put json directly into a step definition because I think it's too messy. Try [these examples](https://github.com/dmcnulla/rest_baby/blob/master/features/rest_client.feature).

```
  Given I have a web service
  And I have "PUT" service for "/test"
  And I am a rest client
  When I "PUT" to the web service with the following
    """
    {"Question": "What is the meaning of life?"}
    """
  Then I receive the expected message
```

I didn't use any scenario outlines, but I think you could do it. Anyways, that can end up being very messy to read. Also, I usually put all scenario outlines in quotes to keep them clean. One more thing, I split up my json messages inside the step definitions, not directly in the step regexp.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, Dave. It really works. But does it mean I should never put json strings in step regexp? It is hard to write such a definition by some other languages such as Chinese or Japanese. Do you have any suggestion for the case?

Comment: I wouldn't. If your json is super simple like { "id": 5 } then maybe you can specific it like And I call "<url>" with id "5" then just stuff it into the json message and send it. It's just too hard for anything complex. It's not worth it because it will slow your productivity.